# Which data types are no longer recommended to use in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have read from the internet that unless you work with old version sql server databases, now `datetime2` is recommended to use.

It is just one type I know. Is there a list of data types which we should avoid using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under ["Features Not Supported in a Future Version of SQL Server"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx) in MSDN

- text
- ntext
- image
- timestamp alias for rowversion

datetime2 + date + time are new types with SQL Server 2008